# Alternative to <?php ob_start(); ?> ..<?php ob_flush(); ?>

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is there any alternative available to

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

Codes go here..........

<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

for eliminating `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at............`

I'm looking for an alternative `.htaccess` rewrite rule to the above PHP functions.

Thanks,

Comment: what headers are you sending?

Comment: May I ask why you're looking at an alternative to the .htaccess rewrite rule?

Comment: Solve your problem instead of trying to find a way around it. Most likely you accidentially output something, maybe a stray blank.

Comment: check your white space around your php tags.  If you have any white space between closing and opening tags or between top of the document and an opening tag or bottom of the document and the closing tag it will unintentionally send the headers.

Comment: not an alternative to to the .htaccess rewrite rule but alternative to the functions `<?php ob_start(); ?>Codes go here..........<?php ob_flush(); ?>`. you don't understand my question at all.

Comment: It's hard to check some 100 of pages which is very unexpected. i'm not having such warning on my `localhost`. i'm getting the warning throughout the whole site on `remote host`.

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering. Tip: mod_rewrite can do absolutely **NOTHING** to control php buffering.

Comment: @Marc B,  thanks for the helpful info and this is what i expected to know.

Comment: `headers already sent by ` **read the rest of the error message** It tells you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: @Marc B if it were your answer instead of comment, i would accept it last night. yes, .htaccess is for controlling apache server. my brain was too hot in last midnight.

Comment: @Marc B although `php_flag output_buffering on` in `.htaccess` is a resolution to this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be unable to fix that error by editing your htaccess file unless you hide the error which won't fix your actual issue because the header change that you attempted will fail.

Instead, you need to ensure that you modify the headers before you output any html, text or white space. This error can often be caused by:

- white space before your opening php tag
- outputting some html (such as the docytpe and head) then attempting to change the location header to redirect to another page

Comment: thanks, but don't many developers have to output some html (such as the docytpe and head) then attempting to change the location header to redirect to another page? this is a very common and obvious issue.

Comment: @SilentPond that's exactly why there are the ob_* functions for which you are trying to find alternatives. They DO work, just make sure you don't output anything before writing response headers.

Comment: If you want to do an immediate redirect, then there is no point in showing any output. If you want to do a redirect after a few seconds, nothing stops you from specifying it before any output

Comment: @SilentPond unfortunately you can't send output and then change the headers so you need to either use ob_* functions or change the headers before you send output.

Answer (score 1):

The true "alternative" (which really isn't an alternative, but is instead the right way) is structuring your code so that no header is set after the output has started.

There is really no case when this is not possible, and output buffering is not meant to be used as a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative and simple resolution to this problem is to enable `output_buffering` variable on the PHP server which can be easily done by saving the following code in php.ini file.

```
output_buffering = On
```